# Is the EFI shell flexible enough to loop over boot entries?

Tags: uefi

I'm trying to write an EFI shell script which deletes all boot entries (as given in `bcfg dump boot`), without knowing how many exist ahead-of-time.

The language provides a looping construct, patterned off that from Microsoft's shells:

```
for var in <set>
   ...
endfor
```

...but I'm unclear on whether there's a reasonable way to get the numeric identifiers of the boot entries from `bcfg dump` into the `<set>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment (UEFI Shell v2.1 and UEFI v2.50) there is no way for parsing `bcfg` output using UEFI Shell.

The only supported method for parsing in UEFI Shell script is by using `parse` command, which require `Standard-Format Output` (it seems to be CSV). Unfortunately only 7 commands can generate `SFO`, by using `-sfo` flag as parameters. Supported commands are: `ls`, `map`, `memmap`, `date`, `dh`, `devices`, `drivers`.

Removing all boot options can be achieved by writing simple C application that mimic [bcfg](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/ShellPkg/Library/UefiShellBcfgCommandLib/UefiShellBcfgCommandLib.c#L630) behavior. I managed to do that and sample code can be found [here](https://github.com/pietrushnic/edk2/tree/rm-all-boot-opts/ShellPkg/Application/ShellRmAllBootOptApp).

Note that removing all boot options can be dangerous in some cases and can lead to unrecoverable state of your hardware. Make sure you know what you doing.

Answer (score 0):

Given this boot option list ( on my system ),

```
FS0:\> bcfg boot dump
Option: 00. Variable: Boot0004
  Desc    - UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell
  DevPath - VenMedia(__ID__)
  Optional- Y
Option: 01. Variable: Boot0001
  Desc    - ubuntu
  DevPath - HD(1,GPT,__ID__,0x800,0x219800)/\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI
  Optional- Y
Option: 02. Variable: Boot0005
  Desc    - Hard Drive
  DevPath - BBS(HD,)
  Optional- Y
```

I ran  edit  `my.nsh`  and input the following few script lines,

```
echo -off
bcfg boot dump 1>v entries
for %e in %entries%
  if /i %e == "variable:" then
    echo "Removing boot option %prev%"
    bcfg boot rm 0
  endif
  set -v prev "entry %e"
endfor
```

( **WARNING** If you try this, it **will** remove your current Boot Options : )

I ran  `my.nsh`  and the output showed -

```
FS0:\> echo -off                 
Removing boot entry 00.
Removing boot entry 01.
Removing boot entry 02.
```

After running the above .. they're all gone -

```
FS0:\> bcfg boot dump
No options found.
```

The shell version here is -

```
FS0:\> ver            
UEFI Interactive Shell v2.2
EDK II
UEFI v2.80 (American Megatrends, 0x00050019)
```